# How can I overcome the pycharm autocomplete problem with Kivy Python?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I am currently using Kivy framework. I have used some others too and I noticed that Pycharm does not provide identifier for the widgets. For instance while it autocompletes the text identifier in Button(text=) in Flet, it does not do the same for Kivy it just shows **kwargs when you hover on the parantheses in the Button() class. I checked the settings but everything seems intact. Is there any additional thing that I should do for it?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE's

Comment: @Ovski thank you very much but I have already tried the solutions mentioned there except for the newest update with the jar file. However, it did not work either.